# Slow MongoDB lookup

Tags: mongodb

I am quite new to MongoDB. And I have a Mongo aggregate query that takes 5 minutes on 10k+ documents. That doesn't seem right. Basically Products and SKUs have a 1-to-many relationship and I want to find all products with SKUs greater than 0.00001

```
products = await this.productModel.aggregate([        
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: 'skus',
            let: { myid: '$_id' },
            pipeline: [
              {
                $match: {
                  $expr: {
                    $and: [
                      { $eq: ['$product', '$$myid'] },
                      { $gt: ['$quantity', 0.00001] },
                    ],
                  },
                },
              },
            ],
            as: 'skus',
          },
        },
        {
          $addFields: {
            id: '$_id',
            skusize: { $size: '$skus' },
          },
        },
        {
          $match: { skusize: { $gt: 0 } },
        },
   ]);
```

Comment: Are you using any indexes ?

Comment: I'm wondering if _"inverting"_ the query might be faster.  I.e., aggregate on the `skus` collection by first filtering on `"quantity"` and then `"$group"` on `"product"`.  No _count_ would be necessary then.  A `"$lookup"` into the `products` collection could then be done to retrieve that info.

Comment: No I'm not using indexes. Not quite sure which fields to index.